# Handsontable: I want to export CSV file without HTML

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I want to export my handsontable as CSV file but its render as html. so when its downloaded it shows the HTML over there any help will be appreciated.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2L2cb02v/1/) code

and here is snippet.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  var example1 = document.getElementById('example1');
   var data = [
    ['ABC', "DEF", "GHI", "JJJ", "KKK", "LLL"],
    [2009, 0, 2941, 4303, 354, '<a href="#"> 123 </a>'],
    [2010, 5, 2905, 2867, 123, '<a href="#"> 456456 </a>'],
    [2011, 4, 2517, 4822, 552, '<a href="#"> 8254 </a>'],
    [2012, 7777, 7777, 9999, 12, '<a href="#"> 456 </a>']
  ];
  var hot = new Handsontable(example1, {
    data: data,
    renderer:"html",
    colHeaders: true,
    rowHeaders: true
  });
  
  var buttons = {

    file: document.getElementById('export-file')
  };
  
  var exportPlugin = hot.getPlugin('exportFile');
  var resultTextarea = document.getElementById('result');
  
 
  buttons.file.addEventListener('click', function() {
    exportPlugin.downloadFile('csv', {filename: 'MyFile'});
  });
  


});
```

```css
</style><!-- Ugly Hack due to jsFiddle issue -->

<script src="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.8.2/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.8.2/bower_components/handsontable-pro/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="example1" class="hot handsontable htRowHeaders htColumnHeaders"></div>
</div>
<br>

<button id="export-file" class="intext-btn">
  Export as a file
</button>
```

Comment: Your fiddle seems to throw an js error, please check the console.

Comment: @DavidR Please check the fiddle now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

**CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    //  Data
    var data = [
        ['ABC', "DEF", "GHI", "JJJ", "KKK", "LLL"],
        [2009, 0, 2941, 4303, 354, '<a href="#"> 123 </a>'],
        [2010, 5, 2905, 2867, 123, '<a href="#"> 456456 </a>'],
        [2011, 4, 2517, 4822, 552, '<a href="#"> 8254 </a>'],
        [2012, 7777, 7777, 9999, 12, '<a href="#"> 456 </a>']
        ];

    //  Function for remove HTML
    function strip(html)
    {
       var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
       tmp.innerHTML = html;
       return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
    }

    //  Test
    $(data).each(function(index,item){
      console.log("With html element: "+index+" item: "+data[index]);
      console.log("Without html element: "+index+" item: "+strip(data[index]));
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**RESULT:**

```
With html element: 0 item: ABC,DEF,GHI,JJJ,KKK,LLL  removeHtml.html:27:4
Without html element: 0 item: ABC,DEF,GHI,JJJ,KKK,LLL  removeHtml.html:28:4
With html element: 1 item: 2009,0,2941,4303,354,<a href="#"> 123 </a>  removeHtml.html:27:4
Without html element: 1 item: 2009,0,2941,4303,354, 123   removeHtml.html:28:4
With html element: 2 item: 2010,5,2905,2867,123,<a href="#"> 456456 </a>  removeHtml.html:27:4
Without html element: 2 item: 2010,5,2905,2867,123, 456456   removeHtml.html:28:4
With html element: 3 item: 2011,4,2517,4822,552,<a href="#"> 8254 </a>  removeHtml.html:27:4
Without html element: 3 item: 2011,4,2517,4822,552, 8254   removeHtml.html:28:4
With html element: 4 item: 2012,7777,7777,9999,12,<a href="#"> 456 </a>  removeHtml.html:27:4
Without html element: 4 item: 2012,7777,7777,9999,12, 456   removeHtml.html:28:4
```

Comment: but after that that will html tag will be not shown into excel. we just need to remove that from when we export